# When does a steam close after sending it as HttpResponseMessage.Content?

Tags: c#, stream

I have a Web API service that sends a file back to the WinForm client, and i do it like so:

```
            var fileResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            fileResponse.Content = new StreamContent(zipStream);
            fileResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            return fileResponse;
```

Now i noticed i cannot close the steam(zipStream in this case) because the Content will not be populated appropriately because the StreamContent uses the stream as a reference.

Now my question is, when and if will the stream be closed?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually when the connection closes.   In this case the fileResponse is in a method (since you have a return) and is on the execution stack.  So the stream should be disposed during the return.

Answer (score 0):

Using block would dispose stream at appropriate time.

```
using (var zipStream = ....)
        {
            Test(zipStream);
        }
public HttpResponseMessage Test(Stream zipStream)
    {
        var fileResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        fileResponse.Content = new StreamContent(zipStream);
        fileResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return fileResponse;
    }
```